# Java to C# - intValue() equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, java, asp.net

I am trying to re-write a piece of code which was in Java to C#, and I ran into a problem, basically I am creating a method which returns a string, but the string returned from c# and java is not the same, therefore the code is fauly. One problem is the following code,

I have this Java Code:

```
Double localDouble1 = new Double(d1 / 100.0D);
int l = localDouble1.intValue();
```

And I want to re-write it in C#, I have tried

```
Double localDouble1 = d1 / 100.0D;
int l = Convert.ToInt32(localDouble1);
```

It compiles and works, but the result is different, in my particular scenario, the Java int l variable contains 0, and the c# one returns 1.

Is there a better method to achieve what I need to do, the same as in Java.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I ignored d1 because it is not what is the problem, to convert.ToInt32 was to problem, btw your suggestion worked :)

Comment: While I'm glad it solved the problem, it's always useful to have code we can run to see the difference - and that depends on the value of `d1`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I understand, will make sure I put all related code next time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Convert.ToInt32(double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx) *rounds* to the nearest integer. [`intValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue%28%29) doesn't - it truncates, just as a cast does (as documented).

Just cast instead:

```
int l = (int) localDouble1;
```

(Also try to avoid names like `l` which look like `1` :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - you are right about the names, I was going crazy because I was just seeing this "int i2 = ((i1 - (l * 100)) / 10);" in another line, and I was like how is this not maching, it's just integers. But I did not write this code, I am just re-writing it. Anyway thanks for your answer, going to try it out now.

Comment: Doesn't this say it rounds? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue()

Comment: @Hogan: It's imprecise - the later documentation I linked to is better. Basically it *is* rounding, but rounding towards zero rather than rounding towards the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Double localDouble1 = d1 / 100.0D;

int l=Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(localDouble1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Convert.ToInt32 
If value is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 5.5 is converted to 6, and 6.5 is converted to 7.
[Explicit numeric conversions table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit-numeric-conversions-table)

```
  cast int l = (int) localDouble1;
```